# Monitor disk read/write IO per second on Debian

Tags: hard-drive, debian, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor disk I/Os on a server.
I need to fetch two metrics:

- read IO/sec
- write IO/sec

Using `iotop` I'm able to read those metrics (`DISK READ` and `DISK WRITE`). **My major problem is that I can't use any non-built-in commands.**

How can I get an instant snapshot of read *IO/sec* and *write IO/sec* without any third-party utility?

Comment: Ahrm...what's wrong with iotop? Not installed?

Comment: By “built in”, do you mean already installed.

Comment: `iotop` is not installed on target server and I don't have rights to install a new utility. **@richard**: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a good way to read the I/O metrics:

1. Get all processes ID from `/proc/` by listing the directory
2. Extract the metrics from `cat /proc/[pid]/io`
3. Do some maths

Answer (score 1):

Look in file `/proc/diskstats` it has the info you need.
read http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt

The files in `/proc` are not real files, they are dynamic pseudo files.

Also, if it does not depend on any non existent dynamic libraries you can copy pstop to `~/bin` then `chmod +x ~/bin/pstop`. If it does you will have to compile a staticly linked version.